# When transliterating into the Latin alphabet, what does an apostrophe mean?

Tags: orthography, hebrew, transliteration

As an example, the Hebrew word for *if* can be written in the English alphabet as `’im`.  What does the apostrophe represent here?

Comment: Come on, it's not that hard to do a little research: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hebrew_alphabet#Transliterations_and_transcriptions

Comment: Thanks for the reference, and you're right, I should have checked wikipedia.  However, my question was more general.  I was wondering if there was a general rule that means "the apostrophe does...", but it seems that may not be the case?

Comment: I'd guess that it indicates a glottal stop more often than not, but there would be hundreds of different transliteration schemes.

Comment: It is often used in fiction (especially fantasy and science fiction, with invented languages and names) to give a quality of strangeness to the words it inhabits. This often results in apostrophes stuck in random locations, with no consistency. The result is an [Apostropocalypse](http://bestfantasybooks.com/forums/threads/apostropocalypse.2100/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Transliteration conventions are numerous, so there are many possible meanings.

Often apostrophe semi-formally represents some character that does not exist in the Latin alphabet.  In some such cases apostrophe itself is an ASCII substitute for a transalphabetic character.

You can find the following uses:

From Cyrillic: [soft sign](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soft_sign) ь

From Armenian, Georgian, Indic etc: aspiration of the preceding consonants p, t or k

From Semitic scripts: [ayn](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ayin), glottal stop

Across a few alphabets as in the Latin one, it is used to represent a preceding acute or grave accent or stress mark, and of course elision.

Comment: More generally : it depends entirely on the language and the transliteration scheme.  no general rule.

Comment: We can say that for the letter 'a' too in theory, but in practice there are more and less likely interpretations given a piece or set of data.

Comment: It's also used in the transliteration of Japanese to indicate an unexpected syllabic break: *shinan* (/ɕi.naɴ/, instruction, guidance) vs. *shin'an* (/ɕiɴ.aɴ/, novelty)